# Change the document root of a parked domain?

Tags: domain, .htaccess, redirect, directory, domain-parking

I have run into a problem which is that my web host doesn't appear offer addon domains.

I currently have a domain name pointing to my name servers.

I went into cPanel to add an addon domain that points to a sub-directory, but all that is available in cPanel is to park domain at the document root which is 'public_html/'.

So traffic coming from the parked domain would get the wrong content, which is obviously not good.

I get the feeling that this isn't possible, but can I change the parked domain document root from 'public_html/' to 'public_html/sub-directory' ?

Or perhaps can I edit the .htaccess file to redirect traffic from the parked domain to the sub-directory?

Basically I want this address;
www.parked-domain.com/

To show the content of this sub-directory;
www.first-domain.com/parked-directory

I hope this is possible otherwise I need to look at a new web host.

Regards,

Dean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its is not possible.

Parked domains does not have any hosting space. It can only mimic the main domain with different name.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, wishful thinking I guess..
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: So do you think the best option would be to switch web host provider?

Answer (score 2):

Try the technique from [Pointing parked domain to a sub-directory](http://www.instacarma.com/blog/technical/pointing-parked-domain-to-a-sub-directory/).

Supposing the Parked domain is `parked.com` and the folder inside the main site is `/parked`, use this rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} parked.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !parked/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ parked/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.