# How to change the document roots of multiple parked domain names?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I was able to change the document root of one of my parked domain name using the method described here: [Change the document root of a parked domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/258323/change-the-document-root-of-a-parked-domain) by rutiolma. Although, when I tried adding another domain name, it didn't work.

This is what my redirection looked like:

```
#Modify parked domain directory
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
#domain1.com
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mydir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydir/$1 [L]

#domain2.com
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mydir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mydir/$1 [L]
```

If there is a way to set custom directory for parked domains in cpanel, please enlighten me as I haven't been able to find such a way so far.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique folder for a domain, you don't want to use a parked domain, you want to use an addon domain. Remove the domain as a parked domain and add it as an addon domain and you will get to choose the directory it uses in the interface.

Comment: I am specifically after using a parked domain for my wordpress network.